# Keras for implement convolution neural network

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I have just install tensorflow and keras. And I have the simple demo as follow:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=10, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

And I have this warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py:86: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(12, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform", input_dim=8)` '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py:86: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(8, activation="relu", kernel_initializer="uniform")` '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py:86: UserWarning: Update your `Dense` call to the Keras 2 API: `Dense(1, activation="sigmoid", kernel_initializer="uniform")` '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature)
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py:826: UserWarning: The `nb_epoch` argument in `fit` has been renamed `epochs`. warnings.warn('The `nb_epoch` argument in `fit` '
```

So, How can I handle this?

Comment: The warning message literally says what you need to change.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As Matias says in the comments, this is pretty straightforward... Keras updated their API yesterday to 2.0 version. Obviously you have downloaded that version and the demo still uses the "old" API.
They have created warnings so that the "old" API would still work in the version 2.0, but saying that it will change so please use 2.0 API from now on.

The way to adapt your code to API 2.0 is to change the "init" parameter to "kernel_initializer" for all of the `Dense()` layers as well as the "nb_epoch" to "epochs" in the `fit()` function.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# load pima indians dataset
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("pima-indians-diabetes.csv", delimiter=",")
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = dataset[:,0:8]
Y = dataset[:,8]
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, kernel_initializer ='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(8, kernel_initializer ='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer ='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)
# evaluate the model
scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

This shouldn't throw any warnings, it's the keras 2.0 version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

In your own case the problem was that you were using a parameter name from the older API version. To get rid of this warning, in the `compile()` method, instead of using `nb_epochs`, you should use `epochs`. Now, the warning message should disappear. The warning message describes the issue literally.

The new API from Keras will often prompt you about that automatically, as they're introducing more and more changes with every new update. However, this warning has no effect or whatsoever on the performance of the model.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `init` use `kernel_initializer` and you should be fine.